# Kubuntu 20.04 crashed and now I am not able to access my internet. I don't see wlan nor eth0

Tags: networking, kubuntu

I am not entirely new to Linux, been using Ubuntu for couple of years.
Recently due to a power outage my machine crashed and now I don't have access to my GUI login screen, but I could get to CLI (via recovery mode and runlevel 3). But my main issue is I am not able to instantiate a network connection.

> when I do an ifconfig, I could only see the loop back device "lo". I
> do not see wlan0 or eth0 or anything else.

I am using another computer so not sure how to provide you with log files. I googled for solution, but nothing could walk me through step by step on how to get the network back.

Your help is really appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
When I booted used Live USB even then I am not able to connect to the internet.
But when I did lshw -C network command, yielded the below result

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
     vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
     Physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
     logical name: enp8s0
     version: 10
     serial: ec:f4:bb:14:c9:45
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33Mhz
     capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus)master cap)list ethernet phsical tp 
     19bt 19b-fd 
...
...
...
*-network
     description: Network controller
     product: BCM4352 802.11AC Wireless Network Adapter
     vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
     Physical id: 0
...
...
...
```

My /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml shows the following

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Bumping this issue to get some attention. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured it out myself.

Issue: Due to the power outage, my kernel and my wifi driver got into a corrupted state.

Solution:

1. Go into grub menu and log in using a previous kernel.
   (this got me into my system without any issues)
   (to get to the grub menu keep pressing the esc key during bootup process)
2. Now to fix the wifi driver, insert your live usb/cd

> Copy the below two files into your desktop
> bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> dkms_2.8.1-5ubuntu1_all.deb

(You can find these by drilling down to the following location
pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and pool > main > d > dkms)

3. Now install using the following command in terminal

> cd ~/Desktop sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb sudo
> modprobe wl

Your wireless should now be working.

4. For corrupted kernel, I did not do anything yet. I just removed the corrupted kernel manually. You can find relevant articles in web on how to remove kernel safely.